# Arc length vs plane measure

Tags: measure-theory

On the real line a given line segment, i.e. an interval, has non zero measure $b-a$ (the difference of the endpoints), but in the plane it has zero measure since it can be covered by balls which the sum of all their measures can be made arbitrarily small.

Why is this desirable to have an object in one dimension go from non zero measure to zero measure in two dimensions? Why wouldn't we want the measure of a line or circle in the plane be equal to its length or arc length respectively? I understand why their areas are zero in the plane but I don't understand why we wouldn't modify the measure in the plane a little so that it assigns such objects their lower dimensional measure.

Or maybe put differently, is there way to define a measure that assigns the typical Lebesgue measure to plane sets but arc length and length to circles, lines, etc, sets that would otherwise have zero area (but not all sets of measure zero, only ones that would in one dimension have non zero length)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is legit, but the answer is no: clearly any non-empty area shape contains infinitely many segments.
Consequently if segments would have non zero measure, by additivity the measure of the area of the object will be infinite.